# Ajustar altura de un JTable dependiendo de las filas

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un `JTable` dentro de un `JPanel` el cual a su vez está en un `Jframe`. El `JTable` carga usuarios de una tabla (base de datos en `MySQL`).

Tengo un buscador mediante **DNIs** en el cual tecla a tecla, con un evento `KeyTyped`, vaya actualizando los contactos de la tabla, y muestre únicamente los que cumplan el patrón del buscador (`JTextField`). Si únicamente existen 2-3-4 clientes, la tabla no se reajusta al tamaño de los clientes, sino que rellena con un fondo gris el resto de la tabla. **¿Cómo se podría reajustar la altura de la tabla?**

**Code:**

```
private void resizer() {
    revalidate();
    int w = jScrollPane.getPreferredSize().width;                   //ancho scroll pane
    int h1 = jScrollPane.getViewport().getViewSize().height;        //altura viewport
    int h2 = tabla_clientes.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().height; //altura tabla

    if(h1<h2)
        jScrollPane.setSize(new Dimension(w, h1+27));
    else
        jScrollPane.setSize(tabla_clientes.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize());
}
```

**Método de eliminar:**

```
private void button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();
        
        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        int nFilasSelec = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRowCount(); 
        if (fila < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar al menos un cliente.");
            textfield_buscar.requestFocus();
        } else if (nFilasSelec == 1) {
            String dni = (String) modelo.getValueAt(fila, 0);
            String nombre = (String) modelo.getValueAt(fila, 1);
            int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
            (null, "¿Deseas eliminar al cliente "+nombre+" "+dni+"?", "Administrador", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
                int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i=filasselec.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    //Obtener el "id" de la fila seleccionada, no del orden del for.
                    String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);
                    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
                    modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
                textfield_buscar.requestFocus();
                button_deseleccion.setEnabled(false);
                label_contador.setText("Hay "+Conexiones.contar_clientes()+" clientes registrados.");
                resizer();
            }else{
                tabla_clientes.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                button_deseleccion.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } else if (nFilasSelec >= 2) {
            int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Deseas eliminar estos "+nFilasSelec+" clientes?", "Administrador", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
                int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i=filasselec.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);
                    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
                    modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
                } 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
                textfield_buscar.requestFocus();
                button_deseleccion.setEnabled(false);
                label_contador.setText("Hay "+Conexiones.contar_clientes()+" clientes registrados.");
                resizer();
            }else{
                tabla_clientes.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                button_deseleccion.setEnabled(false);  
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esquema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar del espacio en gris ¿quieres espacio en amarillo? ¿Podrías poner el ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: @Sal En lugar de gris quiero que el alto de la tabla se reduzca, el fondo va a ser siempre amarillo. Pero quiero que la altura de la tabla se reduzca o aumente dependiendo del número de filas.

Answer (score 1):

La sección gris es el *scrollable viewport* de la tabla y las lineas donde aparecen los datos son el `JViewport` del `JScrollPane`; el primero mas grande que este ultimo.

He hecho el metodo `resizer` que redimensiona el `JScrollPane` :

1. Cuando la altura del *viewport* es mayor que la altura del tamaño *preferred* del `JTable` entonces se muestra la barra de *scrolling*, las dimensiones quedan fijas.
2. Cuando pasa lo contrario, todo el espacio gris va a ser muy aproximadamente del mismo tamaño del `JViewport` del `JScrollPane`.

---

**(!)**
Esto funciona sin hacer uso de *layouts* en el `JFrame` ya que estos tienden a controlar automáticamente la disposición y tamaños de los componentes.
`setLayout(null);`

---

```
private void resizer() {
  revalidate();
  int w=SP.getPreferredSize().width;                   //ancho scroll pane
  int h1=SP.getViewport().getViewSize().height;        //altura viewport
  int h2=T.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().height;//altura tabla

  if(h1<h2)
    SP.setSize(new Dimension(w,h1+27));
  else
    SP.setSize(T.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize());
}
```

Por si hiciera falta a continuación dejo el código completo de la aplicación de prueba:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JScrollPane SP;
  private JTable T;
  private Model M;
  private JButton bAdd;
  private JButton bRemove;

  public MainApp() {
    setSize(550,450);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    contentPane=new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    add(contentPane);

    M=new Model();
    T=new JTable(M);
    T.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(
                   T.getPreferredSize().width,T.getRowHeight()*20));
    SP=new JScrollPane(T);
    SP.setBounds(10,10,1,1);
    contentPane.add(SP);

    bAdd=new JButton("Add");
    bRemove=new JButton("Remove");
    bAdd.setBounds(20,370,90,25);
    bRemove.setBounds(180,370,90,25);
    bAdd.addActionListener(e->add());
    bRemove.addActionListener(e->remove());
    contentPane.add(bAdd);
    contentPane.add(bRemove);

    fill();//cargar datos de inicio
  }

  private void fill() {
    for(int i=1;i<=15;i++)
      M.addRow(new Object[]{"000"+i,"Nombre "+i,"Apellido "+i,"2837272"+i,
                            "Dieccion "+i,"Ciudad "+i,"email"+i+"@icloud.com"});

    resizer();
  }

  /**
   * Metodo resizer, para redimensionar el JScrollPane.
   *  Cuando la altura del viewport (espacio de las lineas con los datos) es mayor
   *  que la altura del tamano preferred de la tabla (espacio gris vacio) entonces 
   *  se muestra la barra de scrolling, las dimensiones quedan fijas.
   *
   *  En el caso contrario todo el espacio gris sera aproximadamente del mismo
   *  tamano del viewport.
   */
  private void resizer() {
    revalidate();
    int w=SP.getPreferredSize().width;                   //ancho scroll pane
    int h1=SP.getViewport().getViewSize().height;        //altura viewport
    int h2=T.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().height;//altura tabla

    if(h1<h2)
      SP.setSize(new Dimension(w,h1+27));
    else
      SP.setSize(T.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize());
  }

  private void remove() {
    if(M.getRowCount()>0) {
      M.removeRow(M.getRowCount()-1);
      resizer();
    }
  }

  private void add() {
    M.addRow(new Object[]{"nuevo DNI","nuevo nombre","nuevo apellido","nuevo tel",
                          "nueva dir","nueva ciudad","nuevo@email"});
    resizer();
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
      new MainApp().setVisible(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Model extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel {
  String[]titles="DNI,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,TLFONO,DIRECCION,CIUDAD,EMAIL".split(",");
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int col) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return titles.length;
  }

  @Override
  public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return titles[col];
  }
}
```

Comment: Su ejemplo funciona a la perfección pero lo he acondicionado a mi código y sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Me sigue apareciendo el espacio gris. Actualizo el código de la pregunta por el actual. ¿Por qué su código insertado en mi programa no hace el efecto?

Comment: ¿Por qué no resulta efectivo en mi código?